# how do I get data on BRK.B that is listed on the NYSE using quantmod or another function?

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to get data on Birkshire-Hathaway (BRK.B) that is listed on the NYSE.

It seems that I can't use getSymbols because that function allows my to get data from yahoo finance, and BRK.B is not listed on yahoo finance.

How do I get data on BRK.B?

Thanks!
Old

I tried getSymbols("BRK.B")

I hoped for data on Berkshire Hathaway.

Answer (score 1):

The ticker is "BRK-B" on Yahoo. You can import it using

```r
brk.b <- getSymbols("BRK-B", auto.assign = FALSE)
```

In this case, I strongly recommend using `auto.assign = FALSE` and assigning the output to a value instead of letting `getSymbols()` create an object for you.

Otherwise `getSymbols()` will create an object named `BRK-B` which can be confusing to use, because you will always have to use backticks to access it. For example:

```r
#
# not recommended!
#
quantmod::getSymbols("BRK-B")
## [1] "BRK-B"
head(BRK-B)
## Error: object 'BRK' not found
head(`BRK-B`)
##            BRK-B.Open BRK-B.High BRK-B.Low BRK-B.Close BRK-B.Volume BRK-B.Adjusted
## 2007-01-03      73.56      73.72     72.60       72.86      1385000          72.86
## 2007-01-04      72.86      72.94     72.06       72.20      1070000          72.20
## 2007-01-05      72.66      72.66     71.26       71.56       930000          71.56
## 2007-01-08      71.82      71.90     71.50       71.72       760000          71.72
## 2007-01-09      71.72      73.04     71.66       73.00       610000          73.00
## 2007-01-10      73.00      73.18     72.30       73.02       775000          73.02
```

Comment: `auto.assign` was a bad idea fiften years ago and it is time to take it behind the shed.  Signed, `options(getSymbols.auto.assign=FALSE)`.

Comment: @r2evans: No hard feelings. It's not going to change in quantmod because it would break way too much code. See more here https://github.com/joshuaulrich/rfimport. I've also thought about possibly returning a list when `auto.assign = TRUE` for multiple symbols. https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/373

Comment: @r2evans And that is the correct take.  Josh knowns I had that aforementioned option set for about as long as the package existed.  So yes, the path forward is via [rfimport](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/rfimport),  Now we just have to see what we can do about the glacial speed of change <grin>